# Proper way to define const through the chain

Tags: c

Take the following example where I want to get a `const` **dog** and **cat** object:

```
// place 1 (type declaration)
const typedef struct Animal {
    int id;         
    char* name;
} Animal;

// place 2 (singleton creation/assignment)
const Animal Dog =  {1, "Dog"};
const Animal Cat =  {2, "Cat"};


// place 3 (reference of singleton)
void main(void) {
    const Animal dog = Dog;
    const Animal* dogPtr = &Dog;
}
```

Each time here I am using the `const` prefix. Is the `const` prefix required in all of the above three places, or is it only required on the first, or what's the proper way to go through this entire chain and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const in place 2 is not needed. If you remove the const, you still cannot change the values of `Dog` and `Cat` after the declaration because your const typedef. Likewise, the const in place 3 is not needed.

If you remove the const typedef, then you need the consts in place 2 and 3, depending on your purpose.